# How to bind classes in vue.js?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I wanted to know about class and style binding in Vue.js.
So I made a small app, but I can't get the expected behavior.
A simple app that displays points,
I wanted to change text color depend on the subject point.
But all row's color changed.
Does anyone help me?

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li
        v-for="item in list"
        :key="item.id"
        class="failure"
        :class="{ failure: item.point < 60 }"
      >
        >ID:{{item.id}}/Subject:{{item.subject}}/Point:{{item.point}}
        <span v-if="item.point < 60"
          >you need to take a test! one more time!</span
        >
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue {
  list = [
    { id: 1, subject: 'Society', point: 40 },
    { id: 2, subject: 'Math', point: 80 },
    { id: 1, subject: 'Science', point: 70 },
  ]
}
</script>
<style scoped>
.failure {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax this should help you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't need "class='failure'" just below.

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li
        v-for="item in list"
        :key="item.id"
        :class="{ failure: item.point < 60 }"
      >
        >ID:{{item.id}}/Subject:{{item.subject}}/Point:{{item.point}}
        <span v-if="item.point < 60"
          >you need to take a test! one more time!</span
        >
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue {
  list = [
    { id: 1, subject: 'Society', point: 40 },
    { id: 2, subject: 'Math', point: 80 },
    { id: 1, subject: 'Science', point: 70 },
  ]
}
</script>
<style scoped>
.failure {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```